# How to find AWS Docker Repo

Tags: amazon-web-services

I went [here](https://console.aws.amazon.com/ecs/home?region=us-east-1#/getStarted) and started on the first task which is to create a registry.  I later closed my browser and when I go back to that page, I just get the homepage again and if I start that wizard, it acts as if I've never done it before and forces me to create a new repository.

How the heck do I get back to the repository I created initially and then how can I continue on with this wizard to the next steps with that repo?  Or do I lose the repo entirely until I get through all steps in this wizard?  Where the heck did my repo go?  It says it exists but where?  How do I get to back to that repo on the AWS control panel?

Answer (score 0):

https://console.aws.amazon.com/ecs/home?region=us-east-1#/repositories

no? I couldn't comment instead of posting as answer due to insufficient reputation, sorry for that.